# Why doesn't my audio work in Quicktime (but does in other players) when combining an mp3 and video file using FFmpeg?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, mp3, quicktime

I'm trying to denoise the audio in a video. I've determined that this isn't really possible in ffmpeg, so I've extracted the audio from the video this way.

```
$ ffmpeg -i found1-1.mp4 audio.mp3
$ ffmpeg -i found1-1.mp4 -an -c:v copy videomute.mp4
```

I then cleaned up the audio in an external program and I'd like to now recombine it with the video file. This is where things break down for me. WHen I recombine the audio with the video with the following command, the audio is not present (nor is the volume slider) in quicktime. It IS however present when I play the movie with VLC ffplay.

```
ffmpeg -i clean_audio.mp3 -i videomute.mp4 -acodec copy -vcodec copy output.mp4
```

I thought it might be something with the audio file but it turns out the original audio doesn't work either in quicktime.

```
ffmpeg -i orig_audio.mp3 -i videomute.mp4 -acodec copy -vcodec copy output.mp4
```

What's going on? My concern is that something is wrong with the encoding of the video, and that since I make a comercial product, some of my users will not be able to hear the audio properly in some players. What am I doing wrong?

Some additional cli info that might be useful:

```
my_user@bens.local 09:40 AM /Volumes/ben_lib_red_external_drive/storage/idance/resources_master/lessons/raw_source/skippy_blair/tmp >
$ ffprobe found1-1.mp4 

ffprobe version 2.2.1 Copyright (c) 2007-2014 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Jun  5 2014 19:48:42 with Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.38) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/2.2.1 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-nonfree --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --enable-vda --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-libx264 --enable-libfaac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libxvid --enable-libfreetype --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libass --enable-ffplay
  libavutil      52. 66.100 / 52. 66.100
  libavcodec     55. 52.102 / 55. 52.102
  libavformat    55. 33.100 / 55. 33.100
  libavdevice    55. 10.100 / 55. 10.100
  libavfilter     4.  2.100 /  4.  2.100
  libavresample   1.  2.  0 /  1.  2.  0
  libswscale      2.  5.102 /  2.  5.102
  libswresample   0. 18.100 /  0. 18.100
  libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'found1-1.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp42isomavc1
    creation_time   : 2014-09-15 18:23:44
    encoder         : HandBrake 0.9.9 2013052900
  Duration: 00:59:36.47, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 876 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, smpte170m), 720x544, 725 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2014-09-15 18:23:44
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 145 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2014-09-15 18:23:44


my_user@bens.local 09:40 AM /Volumes/ben_lib_red_external_drive/storage/idance/resources_master/lessons/raw_source/skippy_blair/tmp >
$ ffmpeg -i found1-1.mp4 audio.mp3

ffmpeg version 2.2.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Jun  5 2014 19:48:42 with Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.38) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/2.2.1 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-nonfree --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --enable-vda --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-libx264 --enable-libfaac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libxvid --enable-libfreetype --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libass --enable-ffplay
  libavutil      52. 66.100 / 52. 66.100
  libavcodec     55. 52.102 / 55. 52.102
  libavformat    55. 33.100 / 55. 33.100
  libavdevice    55. 10.100 / 55. 10.100
  libavfilter     4.  2.100 /  4.  2.100
  libavresample   1.  2.  0 /  1.  2.  0
  libswscale      2.  5.102 /  2.  5.102
  libswresample   0. 18.100 /  0. 18.100
  libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'found1-1.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp42isomavc1
    creation_time   : 2014-09-15 18:23:44
    encoder         : HandBrake 0.9.9 2013052900
  Duration: 00:59:36.47, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 876 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, smpte170m), 720x544, 725 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2014-09-15 18:23:44
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 145 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2014-09-15 18:23:44
File 'audio.mp3' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
Output #0, mp3, to 'audio.mp3':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp42isomavc1
    TSSE            : Lavf55.33.100
    Stream #0:0(und): Audio: mp3 (libmp3lame), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2014-09-15 18:23:44
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:0 (aac -> libmp3lame)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
size=   55880kB time=00:59:36.28 bitrate= 128.0kbits/s    
video:0kB audio:55880kB subtitle:0 data:0 global headers:0kB muxing overhead 0.000584%





my_user@bens.local 09:46 AM /Volumes/ben_lib_red_external_drive/storage/idance/resources_master/lessons/raw_source/skippy_blair/tmp >
$ ffmpeg -i audio.mp3 -i videomute.mp4 -acodec copy -vcodec copy output.mp4


ffmpeg version 2.2.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Jun  5 2014 19:48:42 with Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.38) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/2.2.1 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-nonfree --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --enable-vda --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-libx264 --enable-libfaac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libxvid --enable-libfreetype --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libass --enable-ffplay
  libavutil      52. 66.100 / 52. 66.100
  libavcodec     55. 52.102 / 55. 52.102
  libavformat    55. 33.100 / 55. 33.100
  libavdevice    55. 10.100 / 55. 10.100
  libavfilter     4.  2.100 /  4.  2.100
  libavresample   1.  2.  0 /  1.  2.  0
  libswscale      2.  5.102 /  2.  5.102
  libswresample   0. 18.100 /  0. 18.100
  libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
Input #0, mp3, from 'audio.mp3':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp42isomavc1
    encoder         : Lavf55.33.100
  Duration: 00:59:36.29, start: 0.023021, bitrate: 128 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16p, 128 kb/s
Input #1, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'videomute.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf55.33.100
  Duration: 00:59:36.47, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 728 kb/s
    Stream #1:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, smpte170m), 720x544, 725 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
Output #0, mp4, to 'output.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp42isomavc1
    encoder         : Lavf55.33.100
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 720x544, q=2-31, 725 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 90k tbn, 90k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1: Audio: mp3 (i[0][0][0] / 0x0069), 48000 Hz, stereo, 128 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #1:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=107183 fps=10105 q=-1.0 Lsize=  375652kB time=00:59:36.30 bitrate= 860.5kbits/s    
video:316698kB audio:55880kB subtitle:0 data:0 global headers:0kB muxing overhead 0.825099%



my_user@bens.local 09:48 AM /Volumes/ben_lib_red_external_drive/storage/idance/resources_master/lessons/raw_source/skippy_blair/tmp >
$ ffprobe output.mp4 


ffprobe version 2.2.1 Copyright (c) 2007-2014 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Jun  5 2014 19:48:42 with Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.38) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/2.2.1 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-nonfree --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --enable-vda --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-libx264 --enable-libfaac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libxvid --enable-libfreetype --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libass --enable-ffplay
  libavutil      52. 66.100 / 52. 66.100
  libavcodec     55. 52.102 / 55. 52.102
  libavformat    55. 33.100 / 55. 33.100
  libavdevice    55. 10.100 / 55. 10.100
  libavfilter     4.  2.100 /  4.  2.100
  libavresample   1.  2.  0 /  1.  2.  0
  libswscale      2.  5.102 /  2.  5.102
  libswresample   0. 18.100 /  0. 18.100
  libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'output.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf55.33.100
  Duration: 00:59:36.47, start: 0.023021, bitrate: 860 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, smpte170m), 720x544, 725 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: mp3 (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16p, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
```

Comment: > "it turns out the original audio doesn't work either in quicktime." If the original audio file doesn't play in QuickTime, how should muxing with `ffmpeg` provide a playable output?

Comment: Your reading is not quite what is meant. If you look at the following command, it's clear that I meant that re-combining the original audio (not the cleaned audio) doesn't result in a playable file either.

Comment: Do you have any MP4 files that contain MP3 audio that work in QuickTime?